# Is there a way to achieve reverse of maven profile activation by property?

Tags: maven

I want to have a profile that triggers a certain plugin(say PMD) but I want to explicitly disable that plugin execution sometimes.

So I want to have a profile that is always active except when a property is defined.

Something like mvn -Dnopmd clean install, and the profile gets de-activated. Other than that the profile should always be active.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can activate a profile when a property is not specfied like so:

```
<profile>
       <id>someprofile</id>
       <activation>
           <property>
               <name>!property.name</name>
           </property>
       </activation>
</profile>
```

This is also explained in the Maven documentation, [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: Wow that was darn simple, I never thought we could just put a ! (negate) on the property name. Thanks, that solves my requirement.